# Adding function "enableresize" in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas

I'm new to javascript and I need a little help!
So I used this source code: [link](http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/upload-images-from-the-user-hard-driveto-an-html5-canvas-easel-js-application/)

The demo works perfect. But I need one option more for user. That is, that the user, when he uploads image, is able to resize and rotate it in canvas, instead of just moving it around in canvas. (So when I upload image to canvas it should look like [this](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/) , but only rotate and resize, I don't need filters)

Thanks!

Comment: use fabric will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

**Use a range control to get a scaling factor from the user:**

```
<input id=myslider type=range min=25 max=400 value=100>
```

**Respond to changes in the slider to resize the image using `context.scale`:**

```
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
    var scale=parseInt($(this).val())/100;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.scale(scale,scale);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
});
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:25,max:400}).val(100);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
  var scale=parseInt($(this).val())/100;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.scale(scale,scale);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
});

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/ball1.png";
function start(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Resize:&nbsp<input id=myslider type=range><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```